# Different internal energy for ultra-relativistic and non-relativistic ideal gas

Tags: special-relativity, energy, statistical-mechanics

So the energy of ideal gases is $E=\frac{3}{2}NkT$ and for ultra-relativistic $E=3NkT$. I have also computed it for any energy with the form $\epsilon=p^{c}$ and the answer is $E=\frac{3}{c}NkT$. So i can understand the factor of 3 my question is can someone give me an intuitive reason as to why the increase in $c$ gives a decrease in $E$? After all for the same momentum you have more energy per particle for larger $c$.

Comment: How to make sure the unit (dimension) of this equation $\epsilon = p^{c}$ correct ? It seem both side have different unit

Comment: Yeah add a constant with the correct dimensions, like in the relativistic case its c (speed of light) it doesn't appear in the internal energy.

Comment: My thought was that if I put them in same temperature than they'd have the same disorder so something like the same momentum on average of course (each particle) that means that the relativistic particles would have more energy and thus the whole gas hasore energy.

Comment: *So i can understand the factor of 3 my question is can someone give me an intuitive reason as to why the increase in $c$ gives a decrease in $E$?* How is that going to help you understand the factor of 3?

Comment: The factor of 3 is there due to dimensions (like in the equipartition theorem )i just wanted to make clear that i don't have a problem with that.

Answer (score 1):

> Why the increase in $c$ gives a decrease in $E$? After all, for the same momentum you have more energy per particle for larger $c$.

But for larger $c$ the probability distribution (say, in momentum space) drops off much more rapidly with $p$ due to the Boltzmann factor $e^{-p^c/kT}$. This shifts the mean to *lower* momentum and lower energy. If you plot these distributions this should become clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer that made it more clear but why would larger values of momentum contribute less. Now I know they do because of your explanation, my first thought was that it's unlikely to have larger momentum for greater c, cause that would mean much greater energy i don't know if that thought is entirely correct though.

Comment: *why would larger values of momentum contribute less* Because in computing the mean energy you are integrating $p^c\exp(-\beta p^c)$ over momentum space. The first factor (energy) increases with $c$ but the second factor (probability of having that energy) decreases — even more — with $c$.